# Get Value from Json String C#

Tags: c#, json

How I can Get `"id\":-1002112545646` or all result of JSON

var json = webClient.DownloadString(URL);

CSRES m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

"{\"ok\":true,\"result\":{\"message_id\":1,\"chat\":{\"id\":-1002112545646,\"title\":\"ChanelTitle\",\"username\":\"ChanelName\",\"type\":\"channel\"},\"date\":12565259,\"text\":\"Hello_World\"}}"

i write this but not worked

```
    public class CSRES
{
    public bool result { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Parse this string first.

Comment: i wrote a class and Deserialize json object but not work

Comment: What does "but not work" exactly mean?

Comment: Your class is wrong.  It should have a bool of ok and a class result.  You can also try JObject.Parse(json)